# `No overload matches this call` in recharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I'm building a chart in react using `recharts`-- I am using an example from their docs here: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-ellis-30cdb?file=/src/App.tsx

In codesandbox, the project compiles and runs, but you can see the error hint in the code at line 53 (and it generates a lot of warnings in the console).

On my local project it fails to compile and prints the error to the screen. What is causing this, and can it be fixed?

````
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<Props>): Line', gave the following error.
  Type '{ dataKey: string; data: { category: string; value: number; }[]; name: string; key: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Line> & Pick<Readonly<Props> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>, "string" | ... 474 more ... | "animationId"> & Partial<...> & Partial<...>'.
    Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Line> & Pick<Readonly<Props> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>, "string" | ... 474 more ... | "animationId"> & Partial<...> & Partial<...>'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(props: Props, context?: any): Line', gave the following error.
  Type '{ dataKey: string; data: { category: string; value: number; }[]; name: string; key: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Line> & Pick<Readonly<Props> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>, "string" | ... 474 more ... | "animationId"> & Partial<...> & Partial<...>'.
    Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Line> & Pick<Readonly<Props> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>, "string" | ... 474 more ... | "animationId"> & Partial<...> & Partial<...>'.  TS2769

  130 |                         {/*{buildSeries()}*/}
  131 |                         {series.map(s => (
> 132 |                             <Line dataKey="value" data={s.data} name={s.name} key={s.name} />
      |                                                   ^
  133 |                         ))}
  134 |                     </LineChart>
  135 |                 }```
````

Answer (score 0):

The prop data does not exist in the Line chart, you should pass it in the AreaChart wrapper

Comment: No it is exist
https://recharts.org/en-US/api/LineChart#data